# Can a finite set that is odd and a finite set that is even have the same number of subsets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

A more clear way of asking it I suppose would be. Supposing a finite set 'S' that is not empty, how would I be go about proving that the number of subsets of S if the total number of elements is odd, be the same as the number of subsets of S if the total number of elements is even?

I know that the total number of subsets in a finite set is 2^n, given that n is the number of elements. So how can an even sized set and an odd sized one have the same number of subsets?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe it should be possible? Does it say so in a book or something?

Comment: You have just proved that no two finite sets with different cardinality have the same number of subsets - by stating that a set of cardinality $ n $ has $ 2^n $ subsets (and $2^n \neq 2^m $ for $ n \neq m $)

Comment: Arthur, the question is saying to show that they are the same. Perhaps I can just simply prove that it is impossible. I guess I'm just misinterpreting the question.

Comment: Jytug, that's what I thought, how can they be equal? Perhaps the question was worded poorly. Thank you.

Comment: The question is just plain wrong.  Reread it.

Comment: The question (not the title question) makes no sense, as written. The question in the *title* makes sense, and the answer to that is (obviously?) No.

Comment: If both sets are called S there is something wrong.  Is S the set with the even number of elements or the set with the odd number of elements?  S will always have the same number of subsets as S becuase they are the same set.  But S can't have both an even *and* an odd number of elements.

Comment: As @fleablood indicates, you can't use $S$ to refer what (it turns out) have to be two distinct sets. (Well, you can... but you'll only confuse yourself, and others will conclude that you're not making sense.) The function $n\mapsto 2^n$ is 1-1.

Comment: Considering the fact that my professor wrote the question, I assume he meant to write something else. Nonetheless I appreciate the help everyone! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a finite set has $n$ elements then there are $2^n$ possible subsets.

As $2^{odd} \ne 2^{even}$ this is impossible.

===

To determine that the number of subsets is $2^n$ consider that to create a subset you can go through each of the $n$ elements and make a choice either to include it in the subset or to omit it.  Thus there are $2^n$ choices and $2^n$ subsets.